# null id in "MyEntityType" entry (don't flush the Session after an exception occurs) when trying to Session.GetAll after an GenericADOException

Tags: c#, .net, nhibernate

I catch the GenericADOException with InnerException.Message = "Unique key violation ...", for telling the user that the login entered is already in use.
after that I'm trying to get some date (Session.CreateCriteria) i get this error:
null id in "MyEntityType" entry (don't flush the Session after an exception occurs)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

http://www.nhforge.org/doc/nh/en/index.html#manipulatingdata-exceptions

> If the ISession throws an exception
>   you should immediately rollback the
>   transaction, call ISession.Close() and
>   discard the ISession instance. Certain
>   methods of ISession will not leave the
>   session in a consistent state.

Did you throw away the session after the exception and start a fresh session?

Comment: if I do Session.Clear() after the exception was thrown than I'm not going to have this problem, but I don't think that is a good idea to clear the Session for the entire webapp because of a single user that got an exception

Comment: You must close the session after an exception.  I would suggest you rewrite your app to first query for the login before trying to insert it so you can get the same functionality without a database exception being thrown.  It appears that you are currently getting an exception in a non-exceptional situation due to your implementation choices.  Also, it's a best practice to have a session per web request, not a session per web app.

Answer (score 2):

You can remove the object from the context and continue if you do like this:

```
public void Save() {
  try
    {
      Session.SaveOrUpdate(this);
    }
    catch
    {
      // If the object as a null identifier everything else fails. Remove from context
      if (Session.GetIdentifier(this) == null)
        ((SessionImpl)Session).PersistenceContext.EntityEntries.Remove(this);
      throw;
    }
  }
```

Comment: Thanks - that was a good answer if you're doing ETL style operations on large data sets.